# bin log location is not changing

Tags: mysql, mariadb

in my mariadb i have replication, i tried to change the location of the binlogs by changing the configuration file as so: `log-bin = /new/path/mysql-bin`

I also tried to change the index location as so: `log_bin_index = /new/path/mysql-bin.index`

but every time when I restart I see that the location of the binlog files is `/var/lib/mysql`...

i tried to check with `mysqld --verbos --help | grep bin` and I saw that the lob-bin parameter is mysql-bin and not what I wrote in the cnf...

how to I make the MySQL to take the value of the log-bin from the cnf file?

this is the cnf file of the MySQL for sure...

Comment: Were those my.cnf changes in the `[mysqld]` section?  Are there any "include" statements that might have led to overriding your values?

Comment: @RickJames yes it was under ```[mysqld]```, I had ```skip bin log``` but I commented it and it's still doesn't work

Comment: "skip" only applies on commandline args, not in my.cnf

Comment: Instead, comment out the line.

Comment: @RickJames that's what I did but it didn't work...

Comment: If you are still having problems, please show specifics.