# cant change log-bin locaion

Tags: mysql, mariadb

in my mariadb i have replication,
i tried to change the location of the binlogs by changing the configuration file as so:
`log-bin = /new/path/mysql-bin`

I also tried to change the index location as so:
`log_bin_index = /new/path/mysql-bin.index`

but every time when I restart I see that the location of the binlog files is `/var/lib/mysql`...

i tried to check with `mysqld --verbos --help | grep bin`
and I saw that the lob-bin parameter is `mysql-bin` and not what I wrote in the cnf...

how to I make the MySQL to take the value of the log-bin from the cnf file?

this is the cnf file of the MySQL for sure...

Comment: You ask this question on the wrong site, stackoverflow is about coding. Perhaps you should ask on https://serverfault.com/ This deals with server related issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cant change log-bin location](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/285375/cant-change-log-bin-location)

Comment: no it doesnt...